# Debugging SSIS vb.net Script

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, ssis, visual-studio-2005

I am debugging a SSIS vb.net script in a Visual Studio 2005 SSIS project.

Is there a way to execute just the script without having to start in my control flow?  Otherwise I have to work through my other steps and drill down through my Script Task into the Editor into the actual script.

As a side not my script is pretty simple, it just creates a directory if a directory with today's date is not found.

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

Public Class ScriptMain

    ' Checks to see if todays folder exists on sqlzdocs ->  if it doesnt it creates it.  Else it errors

    Public Sub Main()

        Dim todaysdate As String = String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateTime.Now)
        Dim di As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo("\\MyServer\Path\Current\" + todaysdate )

        If di.Exists = True Then
            Dts.Variables("User::FolderExists").Value = True
        Else
            Try
                Dim createdirectory As IO.DirectoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(di.ToString)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dts.Variables("User::Errors").Value = "Could not create the directory:" + di.ToString
                Dts.Variables("User::FolderExists").Value = False
            End Try

        End If

        Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You can execute just the script task by right clicking on it, but I don't know a way to execute the script from inside the script task as opposed to from the control flow.

Comment: I keep a VS Express instance around for just this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

When i was developing ETL modules that had Script tasks, i followed couple of things to help in testing

1. Logging the Script task execution points - I wrote simple custom module to handle that
2. Seperated the functions in the script task and created a seperate Vb.net console project. I executed that project and once it was working successfully, i then included the same in the SSIS project.